# Open file with filename as variable

Tags: c++, string, variables, file-io

I want to create files with names composed of `int variables + ".txt"`. I have already tried this :

`std::string filename = i + ".txt";`

`sprintf` is not the best way - at least in my opinion as it requires a `C` style string with allocated memory

```
sprintf( tmp, "%d.txt", i);
std::string filename = tmp;
```

Maybe `itoa` is the best choice ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a stringstream

```
#include <sstream>

...
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << i << ".txt";

    std::string filename = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
std::stringstream fn;
fn << i << ".txt";
std::string filename = fn.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++11 you can simply use

std::to_string

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string